# Error adding star rating ,How to add a star rating in magento product detail page?

Tags: magento-1.7, products, ratings

This is common question and some people may try to mark this question as duplicate.But my issue is different.Please patiently read my explanation.

We are using daily deals modules to view the product details.

I used [Lipscore](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/lipscore-100-free-product-ratings-and-reviews.html) extension to show reviews on the page.

After install the extension the details page is not retrieve any details.

When i check execption log i got below messages.

> 2016-04-27T08:47:35+00:00 ERR (3): 
>   exception 'Varien_Exception' with message 'Invalid method AdolMedia_DailyDeals_Block_Deal_View::addTab(Array
>   (
>       [0] => lipscore.reviews
>       [1](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/lipscore-100-free-product-ratings-and-reviews.html) => lipscore_reviews_placeholder
>       [2] => lipscore_ratingsreviews/catalog_product_reviews
>       [3] => lipscore/reviews/view.phtml
>   )
>   )' in /var/www/vhosts/abc.com/staging2.abc.com/lib/Varien/Object.php:652
>   Stack trace:

```
#1 /var/www/vhosts/abc.com/staging2.abc.com/app/code/community/Lipscore/RatingsReviews/Model/Observer/Output.php(52):
AdolMedia_DailyDeals_Block_Deal_View->addTab('lipscore.review...',
'lipscore_review...', 'lipscore_rating...', 'lipscore/review...')
#2 [internal function]: Lipscore_RatingsReviews_Model_Observer_Output->addReviewsTab(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#3 /var/www/vhosts/abc.com/staging2.abc.com/app/code/community/Lipscore/RatingsReviews/Model/Observer/Abstract.php(18):
call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#4 /var/www/vhosts/abc.com/staging2.abc.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338):
Lipscore_RatingsReviews_Model_Observer_Abstract->__call('addReviewsTab',
Array)
#5 /var/www/vhosts/abc.com/staging2.abc.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338):
Lipscore_RatingsReviews_Model_Observer_Output->addReviewsTab(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#6 /var/www/vhosts/abc.com/staging2.abc.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317):
Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Lipscore_RatingsReviews_Model_Observer_Output),
'addReviewsTab', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#7 /var/www/vhosts/abc.com/staging2.abc.com/app/Mage.php(447):
Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#8 /var/www/vhosts/abc.com/staging2.abc.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(351):
Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#9 /var/www/vhosts/abc.com/staging2.abc.com/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product/View.php(73):
> Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#10 /var/www/vhosts/abc.com/staging2.abc.com/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product/View.php(144):
Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_View->initProductLayout(Object(AdolMedia_DailyDeals_Model_Product),
Object(Mage_Catalog_ProductController))
#11 /var/www/vhosts/abc.com/staging2.abc.com/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/ProductController.php(132):
Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_View->prepareAndRender(3553,
Object(Mage_Catalog_ProductController), Object(Varien_Object))
#12 /var/www/vhosts/abc.com/staging2.abc.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419):
Mage_Catalog_ProductController->viewAction()
#13 /var/www/vhosts/abc.com/staging2.abc.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250):
Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#14 /var/www/vhosts/abc.com/staging2.abc.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176):
Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#15 /var/www/vhosts/abc.com/staging2.abc.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354):
Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#16 /var/www/vhosts/abc.com/staging2.abc.com/app/Mage.php(683):
Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#17 /var/www/vhosts/abc.com/staging2.abc.com/index.php(87):
Mage::run('', 'store')
#18 {main}
```

I can understand that two modules(**dailydeals** and **Lipscore**) has some clashes but i don't know how to fix this.
Please help me to short this out.
**Magento version 1.7**

Comment: check where `Lipscore` adding tab in product detail remove that and call it grammatically may be solve the issue .

Comment: Thank you,This is some thing overriding issue. lipscore module overriding daily deals module.If i use my default template there were no issue on product detail page

Comment: then it is a template issue?

Comment: I cnt tell yes because my knowledge in template very less.

Comment: i think the issue are both are adding their tab. that issue is conflicting as far i understand

Comment: Cnt we assign the lipscore tabs to load in daily deals too using xml somehow?

Comment: how can i show you the code?