# collection (a anb b) or ( b and a)

Tags: magento-1.9, collection

How to get magento `collection` by next condition:

```
where (url_from = "1" AND url_to = "2") 
OR    (url_from = "2" AND url_to = "1")
```

Thank you!

Comment: it's hard to understadn from you given code so i guess you want something like that     `$_products->addFieldToFilter('url_from', array('in' => array(1,2)));
    $_products->addFieldToFilter('url_to', array('in' => array(2,1)));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want something like that

```
$_products->addFieldToFilter('url_from', array('in' => array(1,2))); 
$_products->addFieldToFilter('url_to', array('in' => array(2,1)));
```

Comment: That's the thing I need ) It will do the job. Thanks

Comment: @qaisar can you please help me in this question http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112860/error-adding-star-rating-how-to-add-a-star-rating-in-magento-product-detail-pag

Comment: @fmrng still waiting for your  answer

Comment: Trying to figure out, it's kinda complicated... while your solution is easy and would probably work fine in this case (it's unlikely I guess that to and from are equal), it is not logically correct, since it would be true even for combinations that shouldn't be true, like `url_from=1 AND url_to=1`.

Comment: @fmrng i was not sure too that why i put as comment but I like your answer why the delete that. It is a great effort put it there.

Comment: Sorry, but I realised after I posted that what it was doing was `WHERE ((url_from = '1') OR (url_to = '2')) AND ((url_from = '2') OR (url_to = '1'))`, which is obviously not correct

Comment: no reason for down-vote?